# UISearchBar delegates not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I have a UISearchBar in my view, I try to use this code to capture the text that User is typing and when the button is clicked to cancel:

```
@interface ClienteViewController : UIViewController <UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate>{

    IBOutlet UISearchBar *search;//is connected
}

- (void)viewDidLoad{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    search.delegate = self;

}

-(void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    NSLog(@"Cancel");
}


-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    NSLog(@"GO");
}

-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope {
    NSLog(@"Search string is -> %@",searchText);
}
```

My code appear to be very simple, all I want to do is find a way to get the text you're typing the User, to know when the cancel button is clicked, and show the results on the console, but it does not work, what can be happening?

Comment: Have you checked to see if search bar is nil in view did load?

Comment: i think so, For me it is nil, no have a text inside (only a placeholder defined inside the xcode[attributes inspector]), if not, how can I do this?

Comment: if you breakpoint in view did load and `po search` do you get nil or the instance. If nil then you can't assign delegate to nil. If nil then your iboutlet is connected wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

**.h file**

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *search;
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText;
```

**.m file**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _search.delegate = self;
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{
    NSLog(@"%@",searchText);
}
```

---

`filterContentForSearchText` isn't a method for either UISearchBarDelegate or UISearchBarDisplayDelegate, so it's never called (unless you're calling it elsewhere).

Comment: Hi Thanks, but I receive the text when user type enter in keyboard, I want to try to get the text when the user begin editing (Works like a auto picker in jquery)

Comment: @user3781174 I updated my answer to show what you wanted to do

Comment: Thanks Exactly what I want!